# Finite Dimensional Subspace of a Normed Linear Space is complete.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, hamel-basis

I am working through [the wiki proof that every finite dimensional subspace of a normed linear space is closed](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Finite_Dimensional_Subspace_of_Normed_Vector_Space_is_Closed). The proof goes as follows:

> Let $(V ,\| \cdot \|)$ be a normed linear space. Let $W$ be a finite dimensional subspace of $V$ with basis $\{e_1, \cdots , e_n\}.$ Assume to the contrary that $W$ is not closed. Then there exists a sequence $(w_n)$ in $W$ such that $w_n \to w$ but $w \in V \setminus W.$ Then, the set $\{ e_1,\cdots , e_n, w\}$ is linearly independent. Consider the subspace $W^* = \operatorname{span}\{e_1, e_2, \ldots, e_n, w\}.$

I am ok up to this point, but I think I am lost in the notation a bit. From here the proof reads:

> Using the sequence $(w_n)$ from before, write:
> $$w_k=(w^{(1)}_k,w^{(2)}_k,…,w^{(n)}_k,0)∈W^*$$
> and:
> $$w=(0,0,…,0,1)∈W^∗.$$
> We necessarily have:
> $$w^{(j)}_k \to 0$$
> for each $1\leq j \leq n$.
> However, we would also have:
> $0 \to 1.$
> Clearly this is impossible, so we have derived a contradiction.
> So $W$ is necessarily closed.

My questions are: **What is $w^{(j)}_k$ and why does $w^{(j)}_k \to 0?$**

Comment: $w^{(1)}_k,w^{(2)}_k,…,w^{(n)}_k,0$ are the coordinates, in the basis $\{e_1, \cdots , e_n,w\}$ of $W^*,$ of the $k$-th vector $w_k$ of the sequence. However, this "proof" is flawed because it uses without proof that the coordinate functions are continuous (especially the last one).

Comment: It is easier to note that the restriction to your subspace forms a finite-dimensional normed space, thus it is complete. If you pick now a sequence in your finite dimensional subspace which converges in the larger space, then the sequence is Cauchy and as the subspace is complete the limit must be again in the finite dimensional subspace. This shows that the subspace is closed.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I wanted to solve this independent of the fact that finite dimensional subspaces are complete, but thank you for the response!